# How to use ResourceDictionary as StaticResource in Windows Phone 8 (element not fount)

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I am creating a Windows Phone 8 app. In the app I have a ResourceDictionary defined in a XAML file as:

```
     <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="YellowGreen" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="35" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="CommonSetters">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="450"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="35" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="YellowGreen" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red">
            <!--<Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="logo.png" Opacity="0.1"/>
            </Setter.Value>-->
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This ResourceDictionary is referenced in App.xaml as:

xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

```
    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Work_Force" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="myDict">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resource.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="NN">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="450"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="35" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="YellowGreen" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing"
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

And then the easy part of doing:

Static Resources NN work fine but commonSetters is not working it declared in resourse.xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined your resources in App.xaml, your 'myDict' resource dictionary is a nested dictionary within Application.Resources default dictionary. I don't know of any syntax how you can reference resources in nested dictionaries in XAML (as I didn't need this ever yet; I think FindResource(...) from code behind can accomplish this). A way to fix your problem is, that you modify the Application.Resources' default dictionary directly to merge with your 'Resources' dictionary. You can do so by modifying the Application.Resources section:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneApp1" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Note that now you don't have a ReosurceDictionary called 'myDict' anymore. Your 'Resources' dictionary will be directly merged into the default dictionary, that has no key. Then the resource will be resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the solution it similar like the aspx or html page, where we add the reference of the style in required page

in whereever you, it required to add the reference of the page  in page where you have required

```
       <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="yourstylepage.xaml"/>     
        </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

put the above code after `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>`